# How to access my server from an external network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I have a local network and my router has a dedicated IP, inside my network there are several computers and one of them is my windows server. I want to access my server from outside this network through ssh. What I thought of is to use port forwarding in the router so I forwarded external port 22 to the internal ip 192.168.0.110 (the internal ip of my server) and to the internal port 22.
Then I tried to connect from outside that network by

```
ssh admin@<dedicated ip of my router>
```

I got an error :  port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible problems, but the 2 most likely are a firewall (on the router or ssh server) or your router knows about SSH and handles the port seperately - ie it thinks any traffic to port 22 is destined for it.    Its also conceivable that your ISP is blocking traffic on port 22.

Try using an alternative port.

Comment: I tried changing the external port to 2222 or to 8888 and it also did not work

Comment: I also tried to forward port external port 8888 to 192.168.0.1(router's ip) port 80 to try to open the router admin page but it failed also